# Error while linking a custom dynamic library Rust

Tags: rust, dynamic-linking, rust-cargo

In a directory I have a C file and its header

/home/test/c_pro

```
  f.c
  f.h
  libf.so
```

I have compiled the f.c into a dll called libf.so using the following command

```
gcc -c -fPIC f.c -o f.o
gcc f.o -shared -o f.so
```

I want to use this in my Rust project.

So in Rust project I have a build.rs

```
println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=/home/test/c_pro");
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=f")
```

When I run a `cargo build` the build fails with the following errors

```
/home/test/c_pro/f.so: undefined reference to `EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name'
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In my f.c I do some imports from openssl

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/ecdsa.h>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
```

and use symbols from these libraries.

Any ideas as to why the build fails? I am following the official doc and am relying on 2 build parameters

1. cargo:rustc-link-search so that cargo can know that he has to do a look up in this directory as well.
2. cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib  to tell what dynamic library to link to.

What am I missing here folks?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT+UPDATE:

I did as pointed out by @Uli Schlachter and it compiles but I get a runtime error stating that `libf.so` is not found.

```
ldd ./target/debug/test_f
    libf.so => not found.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "I have compiled the f.c into a dll called libf.so" - How did you do that? Does your shared object correctly report its dependency on OpenSSL? Did you build it with `-lssl`?

Comment: Put differently: Can you try writing a short program in C that uses `libf.so` and run that? I bet that this question is not related to Rust, but rather about how to build a working shared object.

Comment: @UliSchlachter, I have updated the comment.

Comment: Looks like you need to add `-lssl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile your shared object with

```
gcc -c -fPIC f.c -o f.o
gcc f.o -shared -o f.so -lssl
```

Comment: may you please look at the updated comment. The compilation does happen but libf.so is empty in ldd output.

Comment: Dont bother, got it. All I needed was to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable.